# Excel VBA Macro: Stopping a find and delete macro 'Run-Time Error 91'

Tags: loops, find, delete-row

I'm new to programming and macros in general I've been working on automating a query result from our credentialing database and the current code I have in place works except once the sheet I am using the macro on no longer has a 2 value in E it bugs out with a 'Run-Time Error 91' is there any way I can edit the code to stop if there are no longer any "2" values in column E?

```
   Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2Macro
'

'
Do
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Find(What:="2", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
If ActiveCell.Value = 2 Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0))
End Sub
```